# Special Contour integral question

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be a circle of radius $r$ centered at $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, travelled counterclockwise, and let $\mu$ be the top half of the same circle. $\mu$ is just the semicircle - not a closed curve. For each integer $n$, evaluate the integrals.
[image]

How do I approach this problem if I don't know the radius?

Comment: I bet the result is radius independent.  So set $z = z_0 + r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$, rewrite the bounds in terms of $\theta$, and see if I'm wrong.

Comment: $\int ir^{n+1}e^{i \theta (n+1)} d \theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by parametrizing the curve as suggested by @EricTowers. (The answer is *not* independent of $r$ for $\mu$, though.)

A possibly easier way to do it is to note that if $n\neq -1$, then $F(z) = \dfrac1{n+1}(z-z_0)^{n+1}$ is an anti-derivative of $f(z) = (z-z_0)^n$ and the (complex version) of the fundamental theorem of calculus gives you a quick way to compute the integral.

In the case $n=-1$, you can still find an antiderivative, $F(z) = \log (z-z_0)$, but you have to take some care in choosing which branch of the complex logarithm to use. (Note that if $\mu$ had been a full circle, you wouldn't be able to find an anti-derivative in the $n=-1$ case.)

Comment: Wow I don't think I've covered the complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus. But parametrizing is something I'm familiar with. I end up with $\int_0^{2 \pi} ir^{n+1}e^{i \theta (n+1)} d \theta$?

Comment: @User69127 Yes, that looks right, except that you are missing limits in your integral ($0$ to $2\pi$ for the whole circle and $0$ to $\pi$ for the semi-circle would be the most natural choice).

Comment: I'm not sure how to integrate that. Almost resembles the integral function $f(x)x^{-(n+1)}$ along the unitary circle which vanishes.

Comment: @User69127 Surely you know an antiderivative of $e^{ax}$?

Comment: ah yes! r and i are constant! Duhh! Thanks!

Comment: does one of these integrals vanish?